# Angular Chart.JS Only One Canvas Rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I created a bar chart component and this is working fine. However I run into problems when trying to display multiple charts with the same component. I'm generating "tiles" dynamically through an ngFor and inside each tile there's a  component. The issue is that only the first tile is generating a chart and the rest of the tiles are not. Apologies in advance if I did not provide enough information just let me know and I'll provide more.

ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let productLevel of productLevels" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6" align="center">
   <app-health-tile [routerLink]="['/details/',group,productLevel.plId]" [title]="productLevel.plId" [up]="productLevel.up" [warning]="productLevel.warning" [down]="productLevel.down"></app-health-tile>
</div>
```

health-tile.component.ts

```
<div id="tile" [ngClass]="{'error': error, 'warning': issue, 'healthy': healthy}" align="left">
    <div>{{title}}</div>
    <app-barchart></app-barchart>
    <div id="counter">
        {{up}} <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{warning}} <i class="fa fa-exclamation" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{down}} <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

barchart.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-barchart',
  templateUrl: './barchart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./barchart.component.css']
})
export class BarchartComponent implements OnInit {
  barChart = [];

  constructor() { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.barChart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        labels: ['4H', '4L', 'Close'],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Inc.',
          data: [2,3,1],
          borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
          backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        }]
      },
      options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            gridLines: {
              // display: false,
              drawOnChartArea: false,
              zeroLineColor: '#FFFFFF',
              color: '#FFFFFF',
              fontStyle: "bold",
            },
            ticks: {
              fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              fontStyle: "bold",
              precision:0
            },
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            gridLines: {
              drawOnChartArea: false,
              zeroLineColor: '#FFFFFF',
              color: '#FFFFFF',
              fontStyle: "bold",
            },
            ticks: {
              fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              fontStyle: "bold",
              precision:0
            },
          }],
        }
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, can you create a reproducible demo on stackblitz?

Comment: @SurajGupta sorry it took a second but here's a stackblitz; this example is much simpler than my actual project but in app component I tried to generate multiple tiles but only one chart generated
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2csfw4?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: You can check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with your canvas id, you should pass dynamic ids to your chart.

For example:

You have to pass dynamic ids from your component to the canvas.

and you have instantiate your Chart in `ngAfterViewInit` ie. after View gets initialized.

Your chart template should be like this:

```
<div class="chart-container">    
    <canvas [id]="chartId" >{{ barChart }}</canvas>    
  </div>
  barchart test
```

and in your component it should be like this:

```
export class BarchartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() chartId:string;
  barChart = [];
  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.barChart = new Chart(this.chartId, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        backgroundColor: "#000000",
        labels: ['4H', '4L', 'Close'],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Inc.',
          data: [2,3,1],
          borderColor: '#000000',
          backgroundColor: "#000000",
        }]
      },
      options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            display: true,
            gridLines: {
              // display: false,
              drawOnChartArea: false,
              zeroLineColor: '#000000',
              color: '#000000',
              fontStyle: "bold",
            },
            ticks: {
              fontColor: '#000000',
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              fontStyle: "bold",
              precision:0
            },
          }],
          yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            gridLines: {
              drawOnChartArea: false,
              zeroLineColor: '#000000',
              color: '#000000',
              fontStyle: "bold",
            },
            ticks: {
              fontColor: '#000000',
              fontFamily: 'Lato',
              fontStyle: "bold",
              precision:0
            },
          }],
        }
      }
    }, 100);
    })
  
  }

}
```

Here is the working demo for the same.
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z7jit7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thank you Suraj! I wasn't aware each one needed a unique id. I appreciate the quick help